# Can't send dynamically created .csv file in play mailer

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to send a .csv file as an attachment through "play mailer" and I want to generate it dynamically
We can send a text file like this

```
 AttachmentData("demo.txt", "abc".getBytes, "text/plain", Some(EmailAttachment.INLINE))))
```

But  when I try like this

```
AttachmentData("demo.csv", List("abc", "xyz").map(_.toByte).toArray, "text/csv", Some(EmailAttachment.INLINE))))
```

Its not working
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```scala
AttachmentData("demo.csv", List("abc", "xyz").mkString(",").getBytes, "text/csv", Some(EmailAttachment.INLINE))))
```

You should also escape the items in your list.